# Change and replace words in a string with C++

Tags: c++

First of all I want to apologize for my bad English writing.
My question is: for example we have a lot of sentences and in this group of words some words must replace with some other words, something like this:

> In this cool day it's perfect to go to park and nice to play football.

And changed string become like this:

> In this nice day it's so good to go to park and cool to play football.

As you see the word "perfect" replace with "so good" and this part is not difficult, my problem is how to replace any "cool" word to "nice" and "nice" word to "cool"?
What is the best way to do this with C++?
Thanks.

Comment: You say _"replace 'perfect' with 'so good' is not difficult"_ can you provide us some code ?

Comment: Strategy wise, why not split into an array of words, perform substitutions against a `std::map` of source->target words, then reassemble?

Comment: Please show evidence of research and attempts. Lots of questions on this topic have been asked before on SO. Surely you've read them, as part of your research, so what problems did you encounter with that wealth of material?

Comment: read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/ yet be aware that requires C++11

Comment: @Xarylem Why would you even suggest regex for this?

Comment: ok if I get it right, your issue is: if I first replace nice with cool, then I cannot distinguish which 'cool' is freshly replaced and which was originally in the sentence. A working, simple although inefficient way is to change cool->nicex, nice->cool and nicex->nice...horrible but works :D

Comment: @remyabel, my bad, initially it seemed to me the user was asking about sub-string replacement in general.

Comment: well, if the job is not too much demanding the triple replacement I suggested before would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) to replace a part of an `std::string`.

And you can use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find a specific substring in an `std::string`:

```
std::string foo = "hello replaceme!";
std::string bar = "replaceme";
size_t pos = foo.find(bar);
size_t len = bar.length();
foo.replace(pos, len, "world");
std::cout << foo << std::endl;
```

The above code will print `hello world!`.

You can then continue to loop that until `foo.find` returns `string::npos` which means it didn't find the specified substring in `foo`.

Comment: Whether this is a viable solution depends on whether you want `replacemenot` to be replaced with `worldnot`.  If you don't, you'll have to go though some extra work of figuring out whether the current match is followed by a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do it with char pointers if you really wanna get fancy.

Here's what I found:

const bool SUCCESS = true;
const bool FAIL = false;

boolean replace_word(const char *foo, const char *bar, const char *foo_bar){

```
    if(foo==NULL  || bar==NULL || foo_bar==NULL){

        return FAIL;

    }

    char* new_string = src;

    // can also do strcpy(new_string, foo);

    int len_old_string = strlen(foo);

    int i = 0;

    while (i < len_old_string) {

        if (*(foo + i) == bar[0]) {

            *(new_string + i) = foo_bar[i];

        }

        i++;

    }
    
    foo = new_string;        

    return (SUCCESS);

    }
```

the replace method is a bit easier, but also less dynamic.